# most efficient way to update all negative values in a table to NULL in MySQL

Tags: mysql, null, sql-update

I can update all the negative values in a table to NULL for one column:

```
UPDATE table_1
SET var1 = NULL
WHERE var1 < 0 
;
```

This is great but I have 200 columns which I want to apply this UPDATE to.

I can explicitly run this same paradigm 200 times, updating each variable one at a time. However, this means I'd have to use about 1,000 lines of code to do it.

If I used an `if`, I could possibly have it done in closer to 200 lines of code. But this still leaves me feeling clammy and unsatisfied.

When I want to do something like this in R, I could use something like `df[df<0] <- NA` and in a matter of a few keystrokes, I'd be done.

In MySQL, is there any way to possibly approach this problem in an concise, elegant and intelligent manner?

Comment: Your design is broken. A database table is not a spreadsheet.

Comment: It's actually a temp table, doing some munging around for exploratory purposes. Towards that end I need to replace all these negative values, which indicate various in-house error codes and whatnot...I'd like to consider these as NULL

Answer (score 1):

You can update columns conditionally, by using `IF()` to assign their original value back to them when the condition isn't satisfied:

```
UPDATE table_1
SET var1 = IF(var1 < 0, NULL, var1),
    var2 = IF(var2 < 0, NULL, var2)
    ...
```

Comment: GREATEST would also work

Comment: @Strawberry How would you use `GREATEST` in this?

Comment: Nevermind - I was thinking that the OP wanted 0, not NULL

Comment: In all honesty, the OP (aka me) was fantasizing about some way to not have to explicitly not type out 'var1' through 'var190', but MySQL is such a primative monster I guess that isn't going to happen. In R I could use `apply` but here I'm sunk.

Comment: @MonicaHeddneck There are ways to generate code automatically, getting the column names from `information_schema.columns`. Google "dynamic sql".